# qf in solr is not giving a specefied field any boost

Tags: solr, edismax

As a simplified example.
I have two fields: `title` and `keywords`.
I am using edismax with the following parameter

qf: title + keywords^2

Previously, it was working fine. I have about 15M records indexed in solr. All records have non-empty `title`. Most records **HAD** non-empty `keywords`.

But recently, we decided to remove `keywords` for most records. As a result, we currently only have 1 record (out of 15M records) that has non-empty `keywords`.

Unfortunately, as a result of that, the `keywords^2` boost specified in `qf` does not seem to work any more.

For that record, we have `title`, say, "*good store*", and `keywords`, say, "*pants clothing*". Now, if I search for '*good store pants*', the solr matching score is exactly the same regardless of whether I use `qf: title` or `qf: title keywords^2.5`. (Again, I think it worked before when most records have non-empty keywords since the solr matching scores are different for the above comparison.)

Comment: What is the definition of the two fields? And are you seeing hits in the field in the output from `debugQuery`?

Comment: They are both defined as `text_general`, And I see it in debugQuery: ex.`DisjunctionMaxQuery(((keywords:good)^3.0 | title:good))`. And I do know that for the record which I am expecting a match on the `keywords` field, `good` is in its keyword field as it is shown in the returned result.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. 
Since there is only one record that has non-empty `keywords`.
Based on the IDF formula used by solr, the base value is smaller than 1. There fore, boosting it by ^2 does not help at all.
So, I think the "solution" is to add more records with non-empty keywords. Of course, this is not a real solution.

See following for output from debugQuery.

```
  0.84748024 = weight(keywords:good in 4161) [], result of:
    0.84748024 = score(doc=4161,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
    ), product of:
      3.0 = boost
      0.2876821 = idf(docFreq=1, docCount=1)
      0.9819638 = tfNorm, computed from:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.2 = parameter k1
        0.75 = parameter b
        5.0 = avgFieldLength
        5.2244897 = fieldLength
```